# Push an array of all sku's on a category page into my $data = array();

Tags: collection, category-products, sku, resource-model, array

I want to list all sku's on a category page in a data array.

Currently if i'm on a product detail page i can push the sku into my data array like this:

```
if ($module === 'catalog' && $controller === 'product' && $action === 'view') {
            $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
            $category = Mage::registry('current_category');

            // Product(s) IDs
            $data['u2'] = $product->getSku();
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to push all the skus into my data array when i'm on a category page that might have 10 or more products.

Here's what i've tried:

```
// Category Page
     if ($module === 'catalog' && $controller === 'category' && $action === 'view') {
         $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

         // Product(s) IDs
            $data['u2'] = $collection->getSku();

// Category ID
            $data['u6'] = $category->getId();

            // Category Name
            $data['u7'] = $category->getName();

            // Page Type
            $data['u14'] = 'Category';
    }
```